# How do I query a specific entity in a mysql db

Tags: java, rest, jpql

I'm trying to figure out how to query a specific song in a mysql database. The idea is to find songs by their ids so if I pass the id one song should appear in the browser window.

```
public class Song {

private int id = 0;
private String title;
private String artist;
private String album;
private int released;

public Song() {
}

public Song(int id, String title, String artist, String album, int released) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.album = album;
    this.released = released;
}
@Id
@Column(name = "songID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
```

SongWebService.java

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response getSongById() { 

    Object song = null;
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();            
        song = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Song s WHERE s.songID = :id", Song.class).getSingleResult();
        em.getTransaction().commit(); 
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        Response.noContent().build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return Response.ok(song).build();
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: That I get no song.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is the error?

Comment: `SELECT s FROM Song s` is the name of the column `s`?

Comment: I simply get nothing blank window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query object and set the parameter value and then get single row

```
TypedQuery<Song> query =  em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Song s WHERE s.songID = :id", Song.class);
query.setParameter(1, id); //not sure what id 
Song song = query.getSingleResult();
```